# Random movement from slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

I got a slideshow on my website but for some reason the slide make a movement that should not be the default one, it jumps from 1st slide for 3rd slide and then back to the 1st.

Then if you use the manual navigation (the circles) and go 1,2,3,4 he makes the correct movement but then he starts to make weird movements, just test by yourself a few times and you will see what i am talking about. My goal is to make 1st slide, to 2, to 3 then 4 and reset, simple.

Site live: http://optential.co.nf/

```js
var seconds = 2; //time beetwen auto slide
var delay = 8; //time to restart auto slide

var slider = $('#slider');
var images = $('#slider .images');
var controls = $('<div>').addClass('controls');
slider.after(controls);
var width = images.width();
var slideClick = function () {  
  var b = $(this);
  $('.controls div').removeClass('current');
  b.addClass('current');
  var index = b.index();
  images.css('left', -1 * index * width);
};
$('#slider .images img').each(function (i) {
  var img = $(this);
  img.css('left', i * width);
  var button = $('<div>');
  controls.append(button);
  if (i == 0) { button.addClass('current') }
  button.click(function(){
    clearInterval(autoSlideInterval);
    slideClick.apply(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
       setInterval(autoSlide, seconds * 1000);     
    }, delay * 1000);
  });
});
var autoSlide = function(){
  var next = $('.controls .current').next();
  if (next.length) {
    slideClick.apply(next); 
  } else {
    var first = $('.controls div').first();
    slideClick.apply(first); 
  }
};
var autoSlideInterval = setInterval(autoSlide, seconds * 1000);
```

```css
html,
body { height: 100%; }

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  min-width: 900px;
}

.header {
  background-image: url("img/fundo1.jpg");
  background-color: rgb(21, 21, 21);
  background-size: cover;
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 650px;
  position: relative;
}

.header .logo {
  width: 230px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 20px 8px 8px 6%;
}

.header .menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 55px; right: 25px;
}

.header .menu a {
  margin: 0 4px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 6px 20px;
}

.header .menu a:hover,
.header .menu a.current {
  color: rgb(204, 66, 63);
}

.header .move {
  color: white;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.header .move .center {
  margin: 260px auto 0;
  width: 360px;
}

.header .move h1 {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 38px;
  margin: 6px 0;
}

.header .move p {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  margin: 6px 0;
  padding-top: 6px;
}

.header .mail1 {
  background-image: url("img/email.png");
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 560px; height: 560px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0; right: 0;
}

.header .mail1 form {
  position: absolute;
  width: 240px;
  bottom: 220px; right: 155px;
}

.header .mail1 h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(203, 41, 37);

}
.header .mail1 input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(219, 219, 218);
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
 }

.header .mail1 input:hover {
  border: 1px solid rgb(189, 189, 188);
}

.header .mail1 input:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.header .mail1 a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: rgb(204, 66, 63);
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.header .mail1 a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(224, 86, 83);
}

.mail2 {
  box-shadow: 10px 6px 15px grey;
  background-color: white;
  background-image: url("img/barra.png");
  background-position: 12% 0%;
  height: 100px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  text-align: right;
}

#btn {
    width: 10em; 
  }

.mail2.fixed {
  box-shadow: 10px 6px 15px grey;
  position: fixed;
  display:block;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 800px;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.mail2 form {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 30px 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: 600px;
}

.mail2 h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
  color: rgb(203, 41, 37);
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 28px;
}

.mail2 input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 220px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(219, 219, 218);
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin: 0 6px;
}

.mail2 input:hover {
  border: 1px solid rgb(189, 189, 188);
}

.mail2 input:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.mail2 a {
  display: inline;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: rgb(204, 66, 63);
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px 4%;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.mail2 a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(224, 86, 83);
}

.mail2 .top {
  padding: 8px 6px;
  background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
}

.mail2 .top:hover {
  background-color: rgb(71, 71, 71);
}

#slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#slider .images { 
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transition: left 1s;
  left: 0;
}

#slider .images img {
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.controls {
  width: 350px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.controls div {

  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  background: tomato;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.controls .current {
  background: red;
}

.mobile {
  min-width: 1300px;
}

.mobile .bar {
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  background: #F4F4F4;
  color: #595B61;
  min-width: 700px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  text-align: center;
}

.mobile .bar img {
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.mobile .content {
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at 55% 50%, #F9F9F9 40%,#B6B5BD 120%);
  position: relative;
}

.mobile .content .mobimg {
  padding: 3em;
  margin-left:10%;
}

.mobile .content .mob {  
  position: absolute;  
  top: 0;
  left: 60%;
}

.mobile .content h1 {
  color: #D6D6D4;
  font-size: 120px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.mobile .content p {
  margin-left: 15px;
  width: 410px;
  color: #929584;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 18px
}

.mobile .content .sep {
  height: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #C24147;
  text-align: center;
}

.mobile .content .sep img {
  padding: 0 8px;
  background: #F9F9F9;
}

.mobile .content h2 {
  margin-left: 15px;
  color: #929584;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
}

.mobile .content .buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 400px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.mobile .content .button {
  display: block;
  background: #010101;
  color: #F8F8F8;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 160px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  position: relative;
}

.mobile .content .button:hover {
  background: #222;
}

.mobile .content .button.apple img {
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
}

.mobile .content .button.apple span {
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 400;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px; left: 42px;
}

.mobile .content .button.apple h3 {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: absolute;
  top: 14px; left: 42px;
  margin: 0;
}

.mobile .content .button.google img {
  margin: 18px 0 0 8px;
}

.mobile .content .button.google span {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px; left: 40px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.mobile .content .button.google h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px; left: 38px;
  margin: 0;
}

.mobile .content .button.google h3 b {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: 'Cardo', serif;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 4px
}

.contact {
  min-width: 1100px;
  background-image: url("img/fundo2es.jpg");
  background-color: rgb(21, 21, 21);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height:750px;
  color:white;
}

.contact .textocon {
  text-align: right;
  padding: 55px 75px 0 0;
}

.contact .textocon div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 290px
}

.contact .textocon h1 {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 42px;
  margin: 6px 0;
}

.contact .textocon p {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 19px;
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  margin: 6px 0;
  padding-top: 6px;
}

.contact .col1 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 410px;
  padding: 10px 6px 10px 60px;
}

.contact .col1 h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: 4px 0;
}

.contact .col1 input {
  width: 380px;
  height: 20px;
}

.contact .col1 input,
.contact .col2 textarea {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 14px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: white;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid rgb(172, 161, 160);
  margin: 6px 0;
}
.contact .col1 input:focus,
.contact .col2 textarea:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.contact .col2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 560px);
  padding: 52px 10px 10px 0;
  text-align: right;
}

.contact .col2 textarea {
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 112px;
}

.contact .col2 #btn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: rgb(204, 66, 63);
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.contact .col2 a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(224, 86, 83);
}

.contact .info {
  padding: 10px 60px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.contact .info h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.contact .info p {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 12px;
}

.contact .info a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
.contact .info a:hover {
  color: #ddd;
}

.contact .info img {
  width: 32px;
  margin: 6px;
}
.contact .info img:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/fixedbar.js"></script>
    <script src="js/slider.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title> Layout </title>
  </head>
  <body>


    <div class="header" id="top">
      <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png">
      <div class="menu">
        <a href="#" class="current">Home</a>
        <a href="#tour">Product Tour</a>
        <a href="#">Pricing</a>
        <a href="#">Try</a>
        <a href="#vision">Vision</a>
      </div>
      <div class="move">
        <div class="center">
          <h1>Move work forward!</h1>
          <p>Optential keeps your team organized, connected, and focused on results.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mail1">
        <form action="form/form.php" method="post">
          <h1>Try Now!</h1>
          <input name="Email" class="Email" type="text" placeholder="Enter your Email address ...">
          <input type="submit" value="Get started for free">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="mail2">
        <form action="form/form.php" method="post">
        <h1>Try Now!</h1>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Your Email here...">
        <input type="submit" id ="btn" value="Get started for free">
        <a class="top" href="#top">Top</a>
      </form>
    </div>


    <div id="slider">
        <div class="images">
          <div class="controls">
          <img src="img/3.png" alt="Image-1" />
          <img src="img/2.png" alt="Image-2" />
          <img src="img/1.png" alt="Image-3" />
          <img src="img/4.png" alt="Image-4" />
        </div> 
      </div>
    </div>

     <div class="mobile">
      <div class="bar">
        <img src="img/barra2.png">
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <img class="mobimg" src="https://jsbin-user-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/rafaelcastrocouto/mob.png">
        <div class="mob">
          <h1>Mobile</h1>
          <p>Optential combines the best of responsive software with native IOS and Android apps to provide the best experience and optimal results!</p>
          <p>On laptops, desktops, tablets and phones, always get the best experience on the most intuitive project management set of tools in the world!</p>
          <p class="sep">
            <img src="https://jsbin-user-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/rafaelcastrocouto/a1.png">
          </p>
          <h2>Get the app!</h2>
          <div class="buttons">
            <a class="button apple" href="">
              <img src="https://jsbin-user-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/rafaelcastrocouto/apple.png">
              <span>Download on the</span>
              <h3>App Store</h3>
            </a>
            <a class="button google" href="">
              <img src="https://jsbin-user-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/rafaelcastrocouto/google.png">
              <span>Get it on</span>
              <h3><b>Google</b>play</h3>
            </a>
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="contact">
      <div class="textocon">
        <div>
          <h1>Optential</h1>
          <p>A new management system<br>for a new management paradigm!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <form method="POST" id="contactos_form" action="form/contactengine.php" onsubmit="return submit_form(this);">
        <div class="col1">
          <h1>Contact us!</h1>
          <input type="text" name="Name" size="50" placeholder="Name"/>
          <input type="text" name="Email" size="50" placeholder="Email"/>
          <input type="text" name="Subject" size="50" placeholder="Subject"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col2">
          <textarea name="Message" rows="5" cols="70" placeholder="Message..."></textarea>
          <input type="submit" id="btn"value="Send"/>
        </div>
      </form>
      <div class="info">
        <div>
          <h1>Mail Us !</h1>
          <p>Rua Andrade Corvo, 242</p>
          <p>sala 206</p>
          <p>4700-204 Braga</p>
          <p>Portugal</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h1>Call Us !</h1>
          <a href="#"><p>+351 987654323</p></a>
          <a href="#"><p>+351 987654323</p></a>
          <a href="#"><p>+351 987654323</p></a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h1>Email Us! </h1>
          <a href="#"><p>code@angel.com</p></a>
          <a href="#"><p>code_hr@angel.com</p></a>
          <a href="#"><p>code_support@angel.com</p></a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h1>Join Us! </h1>
          <a href="#"><img src="img/facebook.png"></a>
          <a href="#"><img src="img/gplus.png"></a>
          <a href="#"><img src="img/twitter.png"></a>
          <a href="#"><img src="img/instag.png"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<script src="js/slider.js"></script>
<script>
function submit_form(form){
  formulario=$("#contactos_form");

   $.ajax({url: formulario.attr("action"), method:formulario.attr("method"), data:formulario.serialize(), success: function(result){
        alert(result);
    }});


  return false;
}


</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Site live: http://optential.co.nf/
Slideshow: slider and controls on css.

Comment: I find no reasons why you've taken the hard-way. Bootstrap suits your needs : Responsiveness and Carousel like controls.

Comment: You´re right. I did that and im fine now. Thanks.